# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

In my project I am using `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` as

**Tried 1:**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc =  AppStoryboard.Chat.instance.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatDetailViewController") as! ChatDetailViewController
        vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

But still tabBar is visible.

**Tried 2**

I also tried `tabBar.isHidden` but doesn't works .

**Tried 3**

In My `TabBarController` Class I used
`hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`

Comment: `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc =  AppStoryboard.Chat.instance.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatDetailViewController") as! ChatDetailViewController
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this this will work fine

```
navigationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

Comment: did you add a Navigation controller between your TabBarController and ViewController ?

Comment: if not then please add a navigationController between them in your storyboard 
Select your viewController then go to Editor --> Embed In -->NavigationController ...., it will add a navigationController between them, then try with this code. It will work