# How to create global function for selectionStyle = .none

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using `UITableView` so I have 50+ `UITableViewCell` & I explicitly have to write `selectionStyle = .none` is there any way that I can minimise or do a generic one. so prevent writing in all `UITableViewCell` classes.

Comment: Why don't you just create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and make all of you other cell classes inherit from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
```

**OR**

```
class BaseCell:UITableViewCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib() 
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }
}
```

And use it as a base class for all cells

Comment: `UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none` that's what I am looking for :)

Comment: could you check my next question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240247/hidesbottombarwhenpushed-not-working-in-swift ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could probably add an `Extension` for `UITableViewCell`